# NEST elasticsearch POCO's ID property not being set

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I have a problem with my POCO on NEST's search. Currently I can search for my document which is serialized to my POCO however, my id property is null:

```
IMultiSearchResponse responses = await this._elasticClient.MultiSearchAsync(ms => ms.Search<Facility>("FacilityWithReviews",s => 
                s.Query(q => q.Nested(n => n.Path(p => p.Reviews)
                                           .Query(nq => nq.Term(t => t.Field(f=>f.Reviews.First().Id).Value(review.Id.ToString())))))
                 )
                 .Search<Facility>("FacilityWithoutReviews", s => s.Query(q =>
                    q.Ids(c => c.Values(facilityId)))));
```

So my `FacilityWithoutReviews` is set:

```
var facilityWithOutReviews = responses.GetResponse<Facility>("FacilityWithoutReviews");
```

This is my POCO:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name="facility", IdProperty ="Id")]
public class Facility
{

    public string Id { get; set; }
```

This is my ElasticSearch Request & response to get the **Facility**

```
Successful low level call on POST: /_msearch?typed_keys=true
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.2014849
# Request:
{"index":"dev","type":"doc"}
{"query":{"nested":{"query":{"term":{"reviews.id":{"value":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}}},"path":"reviews"}}}
{"index":"dev","type":"doc"}
{"query":{"ids":{"values":["s5NjYWQBRsDWVSSXM-W0"]}}}

# Response:
{"responses":[{"took":27,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]},"status":200},{"took":23,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"dev","_type":"doc","_id":"s5NjYWQBRsDWVSSXM-W0","_score":1.0,"_source":{"name":"facility 3","types":[1],"status":1,"registrationDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","capacity":0,"rating":0.0,"licenseStatus":0,"licenseDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","licenseCloseDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","address":"7 thomas avenue*","zipCode":"12345","rentLow":0.0,"rentHigh":0.0,"basePriceLow":0.0,"basePriceHigh":0.0,"oneTimeFee":0.0,"levelOfCareRangeMinimum":0.0,"levelOfCareRangeMaximum":0.0,"city":"new york city","state":"New York","facilityManagements":[{"userId":"7c7f50b3-1d9d-48d0-8e86-352a84f0840b","operations":1,"isOwner":true,"isActive":true,"createdDate":"2018-07-03T18:24:07.9175473Z","id":"5af82e77-707d-49b8-be35-b570962557c0"}],"facilityRequests":[{"userId":"7c7f50b3-1d9d-48d0-8e86-352a84f0840b","createdDate":"2018-07-03T18:24:07.9175473Z","status":1,"id":"7538a645-0776-4799-83c4-c6a8459bf4c5"}],"slug":"facility-3-7-thomas-avenue","approved":false,"businessLocation":{"lat":40.7143548,"lon":-74.0059738},"suggest":{"input":["new york city","New York","facility","3"]}}}]},"status":200}]}
```

Comment: which `id` property is null? `review.Id`? `facilityId`? The `Id` property on a `Facility` instance?

Comment: @RussCam the `Id` property on the **Facility** instance.

Comment: Ok. Did you set a value for the `Facility.Id` when you indexed the document? If you didn't, it won't have an `Id` in the `_source` in Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch will generate an id for a document when indexing it, if no id is present in the request. This id is held in metadata and returned as the `_id` field in the hits metadata for a document hit (with the original document sent returned as the `_source` field). NEST does not assign the `_id` value in metadata to an `Id` value of the POCO when deserializing.

Comment: What NEST does do though is look at the POCO that you want to index and if it contains an `Id` property (or you tell it which property to consider as an "id" property), it will send the value of this property as the id value to Elasticsearch. In this scenario, when querying for this document, the id value returned as `_id` in the hits metadata will be the same as an `id` value returned on the `_source` document. This functionality in NEST means that you can happily model documents as POCOs with Ids

Comment: @RussCam understood. Thanks.

Comment: Will add comments as an answer as I think they're helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch will generate an id for a document when indexing it, if no id is present in the request. This id is held in metadata and returned as the `_id` field in the `hits` metadata for a document hit, with the original indexed document returned as the `_source` field. NEST does not assign the `_id` value in metadata to an `Id` value on the POCO when deserializing.

What NEST does do is look at the POCO that you want to index and if it contains an `Id` property, or you tell it which property to consider as an "id" property, it will send the value of this property as the id value to Elasticsearch. In this scenario, when querying for this document, the id value returned as `_id` in the hits metadata will be the same as an id value returned on the `_source` document. This functionality in NEST is known as [Id inference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/ids-inference.html) and means that you can happily model documents as POCOs with `Ids`

Comment: "NEST does not assign the _id value in metadata to an Id value on the POCO when deserializing." But how can we tell NEST to do exactly that ? I have an Id field, and I want to get it populated with the _id.